# Watch and auto generate Rmarkdown

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

Is there a elegant way to automatically trigger rendering of a Rmd file, if it has changed ?

Better still, is it possible to preview markdown dynamically in Rstudio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [**servr**](https://github.com/yihui/servr) package. Just type `servr::rmdv2()` or with the argument `daemon = TRUE` in RStudio, and your HTML output will be automatically refreshed in the RStudio viewer as you save the source document.

Comment: This only creates a http server to show your html output but it does not take care of  automatic generation (knit) of the html output each time you save your Rmd file.